# Grails formula field not found

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, formula, hibernate-mapping

This questions concerns the use of the formula field in a static mapping block in Grails.

I am trying to implement a very simple domain class that uses a formula mapping (derived properties), but I keep getting a "`No property found for name [uptime]`", where uptime is a derived property in the Grails domain class. The code is as follows (simplified):

```
class Derive {
  Integer up
  Integer down

  static mapping = {
    uptime formula : "UP/(DOWN+UP)"
  }
}

class DeriveTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testDerivedProp() {
      new Derive(up:10, down:5).save()
      new Derive(up:5, down:5).save()
      assertEquals Derive.all.size(),2

      assertEquals 2,Derive.findAllByUptimeGreaterThan(0.1).size() //fails here
      assertEquals 2,Derive.findAllByUptimeGreaterThan(10/(10+5)).size()
    }
}
```

Running the test gives me an error at the second assertEquals: `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [uptime] for class [class Derive]`. I cannot see what I am doing wrong here, having consulted both Grails In Action and the [reference docs](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.11%20Derived%20Properties) several times.

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong? The backing db is a HSQLDB running in memory with default settings (created by grails create-app).

edit: I am a bit unsure whether I should add a property field for the formula or not. If I do add a property field 'Double uptime', the assert still fails, but this time because uptime is 0. Viewing the object in a debugger show that uptime is null. Still, the sql output shows me something that looks right: `hibernate.SQL select this_.id as id6_0_, this_.version as version6_0_, this_.down as down6_0_, this_.up as up6_0_, this_.UP*100/(this_.DOWN+this_.UP) as formula0_0_ from derive this_`

Comment: I seem to have solved it. Somewhat. 
To make it work I will need to add a field called uptime that is a Double. I would have thought this should be sufficent, since the number returned by the division in the formula is a float, but it seems that normal integer division rules apply - as the result is always zero.

So to make the tests work I will need to specify that all three fields are Doubles. 

Even though everything works, querying an object for the derived value will still give give you null. Go figure.

Comment: I figured out why it is returning null on the property. See the last comment from me under Ziad Jayyousi's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No new answers in a while, so I am posting a sum-up:

- There has to be a field for the formula in order for it to work.
- The derived property is always searchable, as this involved a database search, but the property of an object will always be null if the version that was saved is still in the cache. In short: clear the session cache before search or refresh the cached object (obj.refresh())

The last bit, manually refreshing, seems very unelegant, but I have not found a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

First: uptime is not primitive nor class type. also Not sure why you using mapping for that matter. alternatively you could create a transient property "uptime" in your class and then give it a getter method:

i would use Double instead of Integer:

```
class Derive {
    Integer up
    Integer down
    static transients = ['uptime']

    Integer getUptime(){
      Integer uptime = up/(down+up)    
      return uptime
    }
}
```

then to access it in your code:

```
def derive = new Derive()
def uptime = derive.uptime
```

Comment: What do you mean by "uptime is not primitive nor class type"? Do you mean that it is untyped? If so, should I add a field with its name and type to the class?

Comment: As to why ... usually just doing something simple to know that it works is valuable enough for me.

Comment: class Derive {
  Double up
  Double down
  Double uptime
  ...

Any idea why this does not work either? There is no integer division here, but I still just get 0/null in the tests.

Comment: yes uptime is not a type nor a class. did you assign values to up+down? it looks like the total for up+down is null and 0/null throws exception. check your code thoroughly.

Comment: also take a look this to use formula, in your code you didn't declare uptime: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5688

Comment: Thanks, Ziad! Although I don't think you read the comment below the original answer, as that somewhat made your comment somewhat superfluous :)

As to your question : of course I assigned values to up+down. You can see the code for yourself above. up and down are assigned values at object creation. The only really strange thing here is that I can use the computed value in findBy* searches, but I cannot access the value directly. THAT IS BUGGING ME.

Comment: BTW - I pasted a brief (but runnable) example on pastebin that more briefly sums up the problem : http://www.pastebin.ca/2053623

Comment: Hmm ... your version with a getter will not work with HQL or meta-queries like findAllBy... That is why one used derived properties.

I made a question on the Grails mailing list (http://goo.gl/y4ogF) and after creating some tests (available on pastebin: http://www.pastebin.ca/2053745), this is what I found out:
The derived property is always searchable, as this involved a database search.
  The derived property of an object will always be null if the version that was saved is still in the cache. 

In short: clear the session cache before search or refresh the cached object (obj.refresh())